# Previous entry Iterator -Java

Tags: java

Hi i am using Iterator to iterate through a `hashMap`, after calling `iterator.next()` is there any way to get back the previous entry (i am looking for something like `iterator.previous()` )

```
 Iterator iterator= hm.entrySet().iterator();
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
```

For now I am creating a dummy Iterator to point to the previous entry. Is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: Save it in separate variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of any, but you could store it in a local variable so that you can have access in every 'next' iteration.-

```
Iterator iterator = hm.entrySet().iterator();
Object prev = null;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object next = iterator.next();
    // Do your stuff
    prev = next;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ListIterator` interface provide you with an iterator.previous() method. But of course, you can only get list iterators from lists. So you can do the following:

```
ListIterator iterator = new ArrayList(hm.entrySet()).listIterator();
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, there is no `previous()` method provided, but if you need to access the previous element in the iteration, you could easily save it in a separate variable.

```
T previous = null;
Iterator<T> iterator = map.keySet().iterator()
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    T next = iterator.next();
    //Do something with the next varable (hopefully it's not null)
    previous = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `previous` method. Yet you can keep a reference to the previous object:

```
Object previous = null;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object current = iterator.next();
    // do work with "current"
    previous = current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the previous element because of two reasons:

1. No method is provided for it
2. Implementing such a method is impossible/inefficient with the current HashMap implementation: it stores entries of each bucket  in a singly linked list. A doubly linked list would be needed to iterate in reverse order.

You can read the map source code from openjdk here:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Iterator use ListIterator

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyListIterator {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ListIterator<Integer> litr = null;
        li.add(23);
        li.add(98);
        li.add(29);
        li.add(71);
        li.add(5);
        litr=li.listIterator();
        System.out.println("Elements in forward directiton");
        while(litr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(litr.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Elements in backward directiton");
        while(litr.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(litr.previous());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not anything like iterator.previous() when using Iterator.Alternatively, you can use ListIterator.
Or
you can have a reference to the previous element. Ex-

```
 Object previousItem;  
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {  
     Object obj=iterator.next();  
     previousItem=obj;  
    }
```